# dynamically setting the iframe height; not working on ie and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

I am trying to set the height of an iframe dynamically using javascript and Jquery.

But for reason this is not working in Ie8 & chrome. (But its working fine on firefox)

can some body please help?

Thanks

```
 function resizePanel() {
         window.console.log("ran the resize panel function");
     var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    if(frame != null) {

        var height;            
        if(self.innerHeight) {
            window.console.log("ran the self.innerHeight");
            height= self.innerHeight;                             
        }
        else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
           window.console.log("ran the clientHeight");
           height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;                           
         }
         else if(document.body) {
           window.console.log("ran the document.body");
           height = document.body.clientHeight;            
         }
         frame.style.height = height - 165 + 'px'         
    }};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        resizePanel();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizePanel();
        });
    });  

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        resizePanel();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code works fine on all browsers by changing one line.

Instead of using

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
```

use

```
var frame = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Options_iframe");
```

The problem was Chrome and IE have hidden Iframes and when we use getElementsByTagName it returns us the array of all iframes. so we try to access  [0] index, it was referring to some other iframe.

I hope this will help.

The complete code is:

```
 function resizePanel() {

         var frame = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Options_iframe");
    if(frame != null) {

        var height;            
        if(self.innerHeight) {

            height= self.innerHeight;                             
        }
        else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {

           height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;                       
         }
         else if(document.body) {

           height = document.body.clientHeight;            
         }
         frame.style.height = height - 165 + 'px'

    }};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        resizePanel();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizePanel();
        });
    });  

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        resizePanel();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems slightly complicated, you could just do the following:

```
function resizePanel() {
    window.console.log("ran the resize panel function");
    var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    if(frame != null) {
        frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

Should work in all major browsers.